# How do I determine coefficients of a square function in this example?

Tags: functions

This point goes into plot of the function:
P (-8, 6.25)

I also know that:
C= 11/12

The unknowns are A and B.

Do I have enough data to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have not. You only have

$$\;\;\;\;\;a(-8)^2+b(-8)+\frac{11}{12}=\frac{25}{4}=6.25\Longleftrightarrow 64a-8b+\frac{11}{12}=\frac{25}{6}$$

So you only have one equation but two unknowns.